# IE 8: JS call to new Image() fails when the code is run in a popup window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I've run into a strange Internet Explorer 8 issue.

I have the following Javascript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://something.com/images/something.gif";
```

It works just fine when I'm running it in its own window but when it's run in a pop up window it fails saying 'Image is not defined'. This only happens in Internet Explorer. I'm curious to know if anyone has encountered this and how I might work around it.

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can provide some context or source of the popup.

Comment: If you have a repro site, I'd love to get the URL.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue too. I was using new Image() to store an image so it was preloaded.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I can't seem to reproduce it on the latest Windows Update patches applied to a machine with IE8 on.

Comment: I ended up just working around it. I can't make any requirements on what browser version our users have so I haven't gone back to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't get it working, you can resort to creating the img tag with createElement instead.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://something.com/images/something.gif";
```

Comment: I ended up referencing an image I put on the page with the parameters I needed.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you wouldn't be adding it to the DOM, that was going to be my other suggestion.  At least you got it working :)